# R: Removing zero rows of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00
[2,] 1e-05 2e-05 3e-05 4e-05
[3,] 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00
[4,] 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00
```

And I want to remove the zero rows from the bottom until the row which has a value, it should look like this in the end:

```
 [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00 0e+00
[2,] 1e-05 2e-05 3e-05 4e-05
```

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
mat=matrix(c(0e+00,1e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,2e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,3e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,4e-05,0e+00,0e+00), nrow=4)
mat=mat[which(rowSums(mat) > 0),]
```

I thought that `mat=mat[which(rowSums(mat) > 0),]` would remove the bottom zeros here. But it just removes all the zeros and creates a list with the non-zero values: `[1] 1e-05 2e-05 3e-05 4e-05`

In other test matrices with just **integers** it is working correctly.
What should I change to get the above explained result ? Btw. I tried this too `mat=mat[which(rowSums(mat) > 0e+00),]` and I don't get the correct result.

Comment: Just in case some non-zero rows sum to zero, it's safer to do `mat[1:max(which(rowSums(mat != 0) > 0)), ]`

Comment: @SymbolixAU thanks it works :)

Comment: @alistaire thanks, it works :)

Comment: Your code is not working because the first line in mat also sums to 0.
If you do  `mat=matrix(c(1e+00,1e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,2e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,3e-05,0e+00,0e+00,0e+00,4e-05,0e+00,0e+00), nrow=4)` and then execute your own code `mat[which(rowSums(mat) > 0),]` it gets the result you wanted, @SymbolixAU and @alistaire should have answered so they could have gotten credits, both their answers work.